# Trying to fetch Text from own Jimdo Page by Android App

Tags: java, android, blogs

My current issue is about fetching Text from a Jimdo Webpage and printing it as a News Blog on my Android App.
I am not sure which direction to go now, maybe you have some hints according to this?

Comment: Does your site use RSS? Perhaps you could read / parse the RSS feed, which should contain the data you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, jimdo does offer a rss feed, but that does not necessarily offer what you are looking for. An alternative is to use an html parser / scraper to read the text directly from the html markup. You make a request, parse the received markup and you have a tree of html elements. In there it is not too difficult to identify specific elements are get their text content.

Comment: Thanks alot to both of you! I used the RSS Feed from Jimdo and solved the parsing by JSoup! Worked perfectly...(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm)